# Randomly display and store without repeating stored value

Tags: python, random

I'm struggling to get my code to work.
I have a large list of fruits stored on my PC. Any time I run the program, I want the program to randomly display one fruit from the list. And then save that fruit in `myfruitPicked`.

My objective is: The program should always check `myfruitPicked` if the randomly selected fruit is already in `myfruitPicked`. Then it should discard that fruit and randomly pick another one from the original list. when the fruits in `myfruitPicked` list is equal to the number of fruits in my original list. The program should `break` and print all fruits have been displayed.

The idea is, I don't want to see one fruit displayed twice anytime I run the program. Also because the fruit list is so large. I want to code to work well so  it doesn't cause memory problem or slow that the program.

Example, lets say I have 5 fruits listed in the file. when I run the program it should give me 1 fruit, then without closing the program I will run the program again  to get another different fruit and so on. Now after displaying the 5th fruit, if i ask for another fruit then the program will break and print 'All fruits have been displayed'. so basic the program should know how many fruits i have in the file  and it should keep giving different fruits as long as it hasn't given it to me already

```
import random

myfruitPicked = ''
fruits = "C:\users\Homer\fruits.txt"

while True:
     randFruit = random.choice(fruits)
     myfruitPicked = myfruitPicked + randFruit

     if randFruit in myfruitPicked:
         print('All Fruits Already Displayed')
         break
     else:
         print(randFruit)
```

Comment: One option could be to have a copy of `fruits`, in a way that every time you take a fruit you remove it from the variable where you take a random fruit.

Comment: For starters, you need to actually read the file and convert it to a list of strings. Right now `fruits` is a string, Python doesn't automatically see it as a file let alone the data structure you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I mean in the comment. The reason to create a copy of fruits is not so necessary. Since you will remove the fruits from the variable, not from the .txt file. Up to you to decide!

```
import random
myfruitPicked = ''
fruits = "C:\users\Homer\fruits.txt"
#ASSUMING EACH FRUIT IS IN A DIFFERENT LINE, it is passed into an array (lines).
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(fruits)]
fruitsC = lines 

while True:
    randFruit = random.choice(fruitsC)
    myfruitPicked = myfruitPicked + randFruit
    #Remove picked fruit from list
    fruitsC.remove(randFruit)
    if (len(fruitsC)==0): #All the fruits have been picked
        print('All Fruits Already Displayed')
        break
    else:
        print(randFruit)
```

Comment: In order to process the contents of the file, you will need to `open()` and read its contents first.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just modified his code to show him what I meant. I did not test it.

Comment: Well, testing isn't really even necessary for that issue...and since you didn't do that or even mention the issue, I doubt the OP will accept your answer (I wouldn't).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I modified the answer so that the file is read before. I just assumed, based on his question, that he had already done that part. But probably my assumption was wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I got this error below when I tried to run the above code. How do i fix this please

          

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Drive\Python\fruits.py in <module>()
     11     #Remove picked fruit from list
     12     fruitsC.remove(randFruit)
---> 13     if (len(fruitsC==0)): #All the fruits have been picked
     14         print('All Fruits Already Displayed')
     15         break

TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I got this error below when I tried to run the above code. How do i fix this please
                                                                                                  
---> 13     if (len(fruitsC==0)): #All the fruits have been picked               
     14         print('All Fruits Already Displayed')                                     
     15         break                                                                          
                                                              
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()

Comment: Sorry @Homer , now it should work, there was a little mistake

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. It worked but the problem is instead on displaying one fruit at a time until all the fruits have been randomly displayed then it'll finally print 'All fruits has been displayed'. instead everything was displayed together when i run the program (All fruits and  'All fruits has been displayed). Some like this:

Banana
Mango
Apple
Melon
(and so on)
All Fruits Already Displayed

Comment: You mean you want each fruit to be in a different line? Or what do you mean by all the fruits have been displayed? Because from what I understood, that is what you wanted to do

Comment: I want the program to loop through the fruits. so on each run I want just one fruit to be displayed. Example, lets say I have 5 fruits listed in the file. when I run the program it should give me 1 fruit, then without closing the program I will run the program again  to get another different fruit and so on. Now after displaying the 5th fruit, if i ask for another fruit then the program will break and print 'All fruits have been displayed'. so basic the program should know how many fruits i have in the file  and it should keep giving different fruits as long as it hasn't given it to me already

Comment: So, for example, you could add something like a keyboard listener that would stop the execution until a key is pressed. If you just do a while True loop, it will run until it goes into the `'Break'` statement, and it is there once it runs out of fruits

Comment: It is not clear what you mean with, then, without closing the program you will run it again. You want to put it into a function? and when you call it, it runs again with what had happened last time? Or what do you mean?

Comment: Step 1 - At the moment when I run the program it'll print all the fruits in the file. 
but can you change the code so that the program print JUST one random fruit from the file. 
Step 2 - let say if user run the program user get 1 random fruit. if user click run again, he will get another fruit.  as user keep clicking run, he will get each time one different fruit from the file. 
step 3 - If there are 5 fruits listed in the file. that mean after 5 runs there shouldn't be any fruit to display because program must not display already displayed fruits. this is where the program breaks

Comment: Then you need to modify the code, so that there is no while True. It just opens the file, and takes a random fruit, updates the file (by removing the picked fruit) and it ends. Every time you run the code, it will open the file, take a random fruit, remove it from the file, and finish. When there are no fruits anymore, it will just print it is done.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will do that